# External monitor via HDMI not recognized on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, intel

#### Update:

**Ok, I have no clue what happened, but it turns out that restarting and unplugging cables in random order helps.**

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th Gen running Ubuntu 20.04. Everything was fine until I run the Ubuntu software update this morning. My external monitor wasn't recognized anymore and my boot screen was hanging due to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1874194. After disabling 'quiet splash' everything was fine again.
Now I cannot get my HDMI monitor working again. I am on gdm3 but I also tried lightdm, without luck.
I am not sure what info to post here to give more hints to the problem...

This is from my history.log:

```
Start-Date: 2020-06-15  09:22:12
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.400'
Upgrade: gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.22.10-1ubuntu1, 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.1), gnome-logs:amd64 (3.34.0-1, 3.34.0-1ubuntu1), xserver-common:amd64
 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1), libgamemode0:amd64 (1.5.1-
0ubuntu3, 1.5.1-0ubuntu3.1), gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.2-0ubuntu2), gamemode:amd64 (1.5.1-0ubuntu3, 1.5.1-0ubunt
u3.1), liblilv-0-0:amd64 (0.24.6-1, 0.24.6-1ubuntu0.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (83.0.4103.61-1, 83.0.4103.97-1), xserver-xorg-legac
y:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1), libnm0:amd64 (1.22.10-1ubuntu1, 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.1), network-manager:amd64 (1.22.10-1
ubuntu1, 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.1), libgamemodeauto0:amd64 (1.5.1-0ubuntu3, 1.5.1-0ubuntu3.1), libapparmor1:amd64 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5, 2.13.3-7u
buntu5.1), gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.2-0ubuntu2), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2
.1), libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.2-0ubuntu2), xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1), network-m
anager-config-connectivity-ubuntu:amd64 (1.22.10-1ubuntu1, 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.1), apparmor:amd64 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5, 2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1)
End-Date: 2020-06-15  09:22:37
```

This is from lshw -C display:

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:138 memory:2ffa000000-2ffaffffff memory:2fa0000000-2fafffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

And there is no HDMI appearing in `arandr`.

Maybe reverting the changes is the savest?

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar issue. On an older Thinkpad X1 Carbon.

> sudo dmidecode | grep ThinkPad    Version: ThinkPad X1 Carbon 3rd

Now on Ubuntu 20.04. I think the HDMI stopped detecting the monitor after a reboot. Probably after a few days ago update.

The 3rd Gen, is Intel.

> xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of eDP1 warning: output HDMI1 not
>
> lshw -C display   *-display
> description: VGA compatible controller
> product: HD Graphics 5500
> vendor: Intel Corporation

This has happend once before, I did find something on askubuntu that fixed it. But it wasn't logical. Hopefully I stumbled into something again. Will update as / when I sort.

Usefully twitter says to get OSX!

> found; ignoring